# name attribute in bean for sessionFactory is in 'red' in IDEA i.e. cannot resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, intellij-idea

My app-config.xml looks like:

```
 <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
      <!--<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>      -->
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <value>
              hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
              hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
              hibernate.connection.username=devuser
              hibernate.connection.password=devpwd
              hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
              hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
              hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
              hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
              hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0
          </value>
      </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>


   <bean id="userDao" class="com.blah.core.db.hibernate.UserDaoImpl">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
```

the line

What could the reason be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded this in Intellij Idea and saw no red for name attributes, including uncommenting the configLocation property.

You probably want to check that you've got the correct versions of the libraries configured in Intellij, as the name attribute appears to be not matching fields in library classes, particularly the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean that you're using.